# How can I use Active Directory roles to set a controls visibility

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a windows form which I'd like to have 2 modes. 1 with a basic interface for regular users and an administrators mode with a few more controls. I'd like the visibility of these controls to be based on Active Directory roles parsed when the user logs in. 
Can visibility be controlled on a per-control basis using something like the

> [Authorize(Roles = "ABC\Dashboard Admins"]

attribute, and if so, where would it be placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can manipulate your control by using an attribute.
However, if you are making usercontrols, how about just applying the AD role rule in the constructor?

Something like this:

```
class AuthButton : Button
    {
        public AuthButton()
        {
            var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
            this.Visible = principal.IsInRole("License_Users");
        }
    }
```